# Azure B2C social account failed calling graph api

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

im working with azure B2C and social accounts.
I have setup an app registration and configure a custom flow to allow sign-in with social accounts on my app. Thats pretty fine and works well. It works allso with local accounts.

When i call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userID}`
with any local account the graph api returns some profile informations. But if i try this with an socail account it fails with the error message `Failed to acquire token` why it fails only on social accounts?

Or it´s maybe impossible to use the azure graph api with social accounts?

Thanks

Comment: When a Social login is requested you need to write the email and rest of information provided by the third party (FB, Google, Apple..) to your AAD/B2C when the third party returns control to your B2C so the user is registered correctly in your system. Have you implemented this behaviour in your User Flow?

Comment: Where and how did you obtain the token that you are passing into your graph api request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s not possible to access ms graph with an "social user". For accessing the graph, any service / service account is required.

Behind the scenes -> "social users" cant be assing requiered graph premissions to access them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The note from documentation suggests that:
[image]

For more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#http-request

For Create a user with social and local account identities you can refer to this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-a-user-with-social-and-local-account-identities

Hope this helps